# In asp.net, how many worker threads will be tied up using Async technique

Tags: asp.net, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, httprequest

An app makes 3 simultaneous HTTP requests to web server. using asynchronus technique, how many worker threads will be tied up waiting for the data

Comment: Hopefully none, but depends on implementation. If truly async, it should be none.

Comment: The whole point of using asynchronous APIs is so that threads **won't** be "tied up". When an asynchronous operation starts the thread yields itself and the scheduler will repurposes the thread (this is because threads are relatively expensive (because of the minimum thread stack size, etc).

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't tied up, Because when you’re doing **asynchronous** work, you’re not always using a **thread**.

For example, if you made an **async** web service request, your client will not be using **any threads** between the “send” and “receive”.
You unwind after the “send”, and the “receive” occurs on an I/O completion port, at which time your callback is invoked and you will then be **using a thread again**.  (Note that for this scenario your callback is executed on an i/o thread ASP.NET only uses **worker threads**, and only includes worker threads **when it counts the threads in-use**.)